# Problem deploying ASP.NET app to web server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, sqlxml

I have been getting an error when moving my application from my local machine to a web server. (I have not been getting the errors on my local host)

The code throwing the exception is listed below:

```
Dim sSQL As String
Dim strXSLFile As String
sSQL = "<?xml version=""1.0""  ?>"
sSQL += "<ROOT xmlns:sql=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql"">"
sSQL += "<sql:header>"
sSQL += "<sql:param name='uid'/>"
sSQL += "<sql:param name='pwd'/>"
sSQL += "</sql:header>"
sSQL += "<SESSION>"
sSQL += "<LANG>" & lang & "</LANG>"
sSQL += "<SSN>" & Session.SessionID & "</SSN>"
sSQL += "</SESSION>"

sSQL += "<sql:query>exec objSession_login @uid,@pwd</sql:query>"
sSQL += "</ROOT>"

Dim myxml As New XmlDocument
Try
    Using conn As SqlConnection = CustomClass.Data.SqlConnectionProvider.Create()
        Dim cmd As SqlXmlCommand
        cmd = New SqlXmlCommand(conn.ConnectionString & ";Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;")
        cmd.CommandType = SqlXmlCommandType.Template
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        Dim paramUid As SqlXmlParameter = cmd.CreateParameter()
        paramUid.Name = "@uid"
        paramUid.Value = username
        Dim paramPwd As SqlXmlParameter = cmd.CreateParameter()
        paramPwd.Name = "@pwd"
        paramPwd.Value = password
        Dim oXR As XmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader() ' Problem is here
        myxml.Load(oXR)
    End Using

    strXSLFile = "xsl/Dialogue.login.xsl"
    Dim mytransform As New XslTransform
    Dim myreader As XmlReader
    Dim myresolver As XmlResolver

    Dim xpDoc As New XPathDocument(New XmlNodeReader(myxml))

    mytransform.Load(Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath & strXSLFile)
    myreader = mytransform.Transform(xpDoc, Nothing, myresolver)

    myxml.Load(myreader)
    mytransform = Nothing
    myreader = Nothing
    myresolver = Nothing
    xpDoc = Nothing

    xmlloaddoc = myxml

Catch ex As Exception
    LogWriter.CriticalError(ex, "User Login - Exception Thrown: " & ex.Message)
    Err.Raise(Number:=Err.Number, Description:=ex.StackTrace)
End Try
```

The specific Line that is throwing the exception is : **Dim oXR As XmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader()**

The logging information revealed the exceptions below:

Exception #1:

> User Login - Exception Thrown: SQLOLEDB or SQLNCLI must be specified as the data provider."
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlException: SQLOLEDB or SQLNCLI must be specified as the data provider. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: SQLOLEDB or SQLNCLI must be specified as the data provider.   at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.ISQLXMLCommandManagedInterface.ExecuteToOutputStream()   at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlCommand.innerExecute(Stream strm)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlCommand.ExecuteStream()   at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader()   at dialogue.login.UserLogin(String username, String password, String lang)

Exception #2:

> "User Login - Exception Thrown: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E14"
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E14 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E14   at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.ISQLXMLCommandManagedInterface.ExecuteToOutputStream()   at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlCommand.innerExecute(Stream strm)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlCommand.ExecuteStream()   at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader()   at dialogue.login.UserLogin(String username, String password, String lang)

The first of the exceptions is the first error that came up using SQLOLEDB.1 as my provider, I started playing around with different providers and got the second 2nd exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem that I had was, MSXML 6.0 was installed on my machine but not the server. Installing MSXML 6.0 on the server resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Has the SQLOLEDB provider installed on the target machine? Check that it does and try again.

Comment: Yes it is currently installed on our server and we are using IIS6.0, the problem sill persists.